# Where to define number of consumers for the specific consumer group?

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am working on Spark Streaming to consume data from `Kafka` topic.

If i use `DirectStream` approach , i dont have the option to define `consumer group` and `number of consumers`.

**For example:**

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
```

Where do i define the consumer group and number of consumers for this group?

If i use the Receiver based approach, i have option to define the `consumer group` and `number of threads`[Number of consumers on this group].

**Receiver based approach:**

```
val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Consumer Group concept when work with Spark Streaming DirectStream approach.

As per Spark Streaming Document

> With directStream, Spark Streaming will create as many RDD partitions
>   as there are Kafka partitions to consume, which will all read data
>   from Kafka in parallel. So there is a one-to-one mapping between Kafka
>   and RDD partitions